# Rocket chat: Determine if the app is running in Desktop or browser

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, open-source, rocket.chat

Is there anyway to determine if  the Rocket.chat app is running in desktop or browser?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: desktop or browser? What do you mean here? If it's running in dev mode locally?

Comment: @Mikkel yes its running in dev mode, Since we have a desktop app as well and we can run the app in browser too.
Just want to determine if we can fine out in which platform is being used

Comment: You could look for an environment variable like TZ,  which won't be present in the browser.  You might need to experiment a little because of you are using electron,  the js code is probably sandboxed like a browser

Comment: any example @Mikkel

Answer (score 0):

You can look at server environment variables using a line like this:

```
console.log(process.env.TZ);
```

If you need to access that from the client, you can do this in your client code:

```
console.log("TZ = "+Meteor.call("getEnv","TZ"));
```

and in your meteor methods (in the server folder)

```
Meteor.methods({
    getEnv: function(varname) {
        return process.env[varname];
    },
```

Obviously use this with care. It is a generic method that may present a security hole. If you want to make it more secure, just write a specific method where you don't pass the environment variable name, to prevent any kind of malicious attack.